# FlatList vs map react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have recently started using `react-native` and have come across the `FlatList` component. When using `react` I have always used `map` with an array.

I was using `FlatList` but there was issues when I wanted to change the `flex-direction` of items in the `FlatList` so I reverted to using `map`.

Here are the two examples using both methods:

`map`

```
{
    this.state.images.map(image => {
       return (
          <UsersImage key={ image } source={{ uri: image }} />
        )
    })
}
```

`FlatList`

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.state.images }
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        return (
            <UsersImage source={{ uri: item }} />
        )
    }}  
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```

Can anyone explain why one should use `FlatList` over `map` or vice versa?

Comment: Hi Peter, would you consider accepting my answer if you found it helpful?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

FlatList has lazy loading (it only shows what's on screen, so it can be more performant if you have a huge list). BTW you can get it to be horizontal if that's what you needed to change the flex direction for - just pass the `horizontal` prop (equivalent to saying `horizontal={true}`)

Comment: If you have a simple list (~10 items, no scrolling, nothing too complex to load), would it still be better performance-wise to use FlatList? Trying to figure out when it’s necessary.

Comment: I don't think it would give any noticeable benefit since 10 items is very few and sounds like you're displaying them all at once anyway. So they'd all be rendered whether you use `FlatList` or something else. I would definitely not even think about using `FlatList` in that scenario. However in general you could actually directly compare using `FlatList` and `map` using some of the ideas in here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html to see if it helps in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The `FlatList` displays the similarly structured data in a scrollable list. It works well for large lists of data where the number of list items might change over time. The `FlatList` shows only those render elements that are currently displaying on the screen, not all the elements of the list at once. So that's the main reason `FlatList` can handle a large set of data with a very complex view easily.

The `map()` function is used to iterate over an array and manipulate or change data items. In React, the `map()` function is most commonly used for rendering a list of data to the DOM.

In react-native `FlatList` is recommended over `map()` when we need to display a large scrollable list.

Answer (score 1):

no need to flex your View tags. just add horizontal

```js
<FlatList
    horizontal
    data={data}
    renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item.item)}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```